# How do you save a custom class as an attribute of a CoreData entity in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a CoreData Entity `SavedWorkout`. It has the following attributes:
[image]

`completionCounter` is an array of `Bool`, and `workout` is a custom class called `Workout`.

I am saving my data like so:

```
let saveCompletionCounter = currentCompletionCounter
let saveDate = Date() as NSDate
let saveRoutineIndex = Int16(currentWorkoutRoutine)
let saveWorkout = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: workout)

item.setValue(saveDate, forKey: "date")
item.setValue(saveWorkout, forKey: "workout")
item.setValue(saveRoutineIndex, forKey: "routineIndex")
item.setValue(saveCompletionCounter, forKey: "completionCounter")

do {
  try moc.save()
  print("save successful")
} catch {
  print("saving error")
}
```

where `moc` is an instance of `NSManagedObjectContext`, and `item` is an instance of `NSManagedObject`:

```
moc = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "SavedWorkout", in: moc)!
item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: moc)
```

In accordance with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305537/saving-custom-class-into-coredata) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473642/core-data-how-do-i-store-a-custom-object-as-a-transformable-attribute) and this , I have made my `Workout` class conform to `NSObject` and `NSCoding`, so it now looks like this:

```html
class Workout: NSObject, NSCoding {

  let name: String
  let imageName: String
  let routine: [WorkoutRoutine]
  let shortDescription: String

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
    imageName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "imageName") as! String
    routine = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "routine") as! [WorkoutRoutine]
    shortDescription = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "shortDescription") as! String
  }

  func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
    aCoder.encode(imageName, forKey: "imageName")
    aCoder.encode(routine, forKey: "routine")
    aCoder.encode(shortDescription, forKey: "shortDescription")
  }

  init(name: String, imageName: String, routine: [WorkoutRoutine], shortDescription: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.imageName = imageName
    self.routine = routine
    self.shortDescription = shortDescription
  }
}
```

However I always get an error on the line `routine: aDecoder.decodeObject...`.

The error says:

`NSForwarding: warning: object 0x60800002cbe0 of class 'App.WorkoutRoutine' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead`

`Unrecognized selector -[FitLift.WorkoutRoutine replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:]`

Why does this give me an error and not the other `Transformable` attribute? How do I save a custom class as a property of a CoreData entity?

Comment: You also have a class called `WorkOutRoutine`. Does that class also conform to NSCoder?

Comment: Ohhhh ok so any and all subclasses have to conform and have the encode/decode functions? Thanks!

Comment: Is WorkoutRoutine NSCoding compliant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `WorkoutRoutine` is itself a custom class and as of your error it is not NSCoding compliant, therefore `aCoder.encode(routine, forKey: "routine")` doesn't really know how to encode it, as well as `routine = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "routine") as! [WorkoutRoutine]` doesn't know how to decode it.

Not really related, but please try a safer approach for your coder and encoder initializer as the force unwrap might cause crashes if the encoder does not contain the keys you are looking for (for any reason)

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    guard let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String,
        let imageName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "imageName") as? String,
        let routine = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "routine") as? [WorkoutRoutine],
        let shortDescription = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "shortDescription") as? String else {
            return nil
    }
    self.name = name
    self.imageName = imageName
    self.routine = routine
    self.shortDescription = shortDescription
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

One of the issues I've been having is trying to use Swift 3 and Xcode 8 while maintaining compatibility with iOS 9.
What would an alternative way be to save custom classes as a coredata entity be?

Comment: For sure having a core data model that reflects your class would be a best practice. You can connect your models through relations. In your example the workout property would be a relation one to one to an entity "workout" which would contain the properties of your workout class where the routine property would be a relation one to many to a workoutRoutine entity.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html

Comment: If you want to use NSCoder consider a document based persistence layer. CoreData might not be the best choice for you. If you want to use core data I strongly recommend to use it for what it is its main purpose: a relational database.